# How to get item count of an index in elasticsearch7?

Tags: elasticsearch

When using elasticsearch 6.7,

```
GET /indexName/_search
```

returns the exact total of the index:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : 1527325,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    ...}
```

But in elasticsearch 7.0

```
GET /indexName/_search
```

gets:

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
```

which means total is greater than 10000, so how can I get the exact total count of an index in 7.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of ES 7.0.0, you need to use the [`track_total_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-track-total-hits.html) parameter:

```
GET /indexName/_search?track_total_hits=true
```

You can also add the [`rest_total_hits_as_int`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html#_literal_hits_total_literal_is_now_an_object_in_the_search_response) parameter if you want to get back the same format as in pre-7 versions (temporary parameter that will be removed in ES 8):

```
GET /indexName/_search?track_total_hits=true&rest_total_hits_as_int=true
```

Answer (score 4):

For **ES 7.5.0** using Java rest api client, you can use

```
sourceBuilder.trackTotalHits(true);
```

Preparing search request using the source builder

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(index);
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
sourceBuilder.query(queryBuilder);
sourceBuilder.sort(sortBuilder);
sourceBuilder.from(from); 
sourceBuilder.size(size); 
sourceBuilder.trackTotalHits(true);
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
client.search(searchRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```